# Check if string contains only some values, and not others

Tags: python

```
print("Hello, welcome to password strength. Test how strong your password is todai!")
password = input("Well enter a password why don't you... ")
print("So your password is", password)
print("Well ok, let's see what i can understand from this...")

if len(password) < 6:   
    print("Your password is too short")    
else:    
    print("Your password is of a good length")    

if password == password.upper():    
    print("Your password has too many uppercase letters")
else:    
    print("Your password has 0 or a couple upper case letters, please consider making your password remember-able.")

if password == password.lower():    
    print("Your password needs a upper case letter case letters")
else:    
    print("Your password has a suitable amount of lowercase vs upper case letters")

if password ==
```

This is where i want to ask if password contains only numbers, but i don't know how to do that, i already tried using ands and ors, but failed miserably.

Comment: Use regexp for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 5):

Use `isdigit()`

```
>>> "abcd123".isdigit()
False

>>> "123".isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if set(password) <= set('1234567890'):
```

This asks if the set of the characters in password is a subset of the set of all number characters.

A [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is an unordered collection of values that can't have duplicates. Some examples:

```
>>> set('swordfish')
{'d', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'o', 'r', 's', 'w'}

>>> set('aaaaassssdddfff')
{'a', 'd', 'f', 's'}

>>> set('1234')
{'1', '2', '3', '4'}
```

Sets have several useful functions, for example checking for a subset:

```
>>> set('1234') <= set('1234567890')
True

>>> set('a1234') <= set('1234567890')
False
```

This can be easily extended to test something else, for example if the password contain only punctuation:

```
from string import punctuation

if set(password) <= set(punctuation):
```

Or only alphanumeric characters:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

if set(password) <= set(ascii_letters + digits):
```

Comment: How does this work?

+1 it does work in code, just wondering how?

Comment: @Razor I've added an explanation.

Comment: amazing, short and simple solution. very fast too!

Answer (score 0):

Well, string has only numbers only when it can be cast to int, so...

```
try:
    int(password)
except ValueError:
    print("not parseable to int, so not only numbers")
else:
    print("Only numbers")
```